# Validate a version number with regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing a validation for a version number with regular expressions in javascript. The valid format for the version number must be (Example: 1111.1111.1111.1111) so I have the following regular expression:

```
/^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+){3}$/
```

This expression validates that the version number you enter, start with numbers except zero `^[1-9]\d*`, followed by a period and then followed by more numbers for 3 more repetitions `(\.\d+){3}$`.

The problem is that for each segment or section I must accept 1 to 4 digits, that is, you can not pass 4 digits. I had done something like this:

```
/^[1-9](\d{1,4})(\.\d{1,4}){3}$/
```

But it does not work for me because in any case it accepts more digits than I expect, I appreciate very much if you could help me.

Comment: So to understand your question: 1.1111.1111.1111 is not acceptable, but 11.1111.1111.1111 would be acceptable, as would 1.1.1.1 ?

Comment: You have a simple typo, try: /^[1-9](\d{0,3})(\.\d{1,4}){3}$/. Note that you 'have used' one digit in [0-9], so it should only be {0,3} in the first Group.

Comment: [`^(\d{1,4}\.){3}\d{1,4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/R4hFns/1/) - Three sets of numbers with up to 4 digits followed by a period, and one set of up to four numbers.